# npm copy and compile LESS files using cpx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, less, postcss, npm-scripts

I'm trying to copy and compile / transform LESS files and ES6 files to another directory using npm tools and packages.
This is my basic structure:

```
-src  
  -components  
    -component1  
      component1.js // es6 code 
      styles.less  
    -component2  
      component2.js // es6 code 
      styles.less  
    -component3  
      component3.js  // es6 code
      styles.less
```

And this is the desired new directory structure:

```
-lib  
  -component1  
    component1.js // es5 code 
    styles.css  
  -component2  
    component2.js // es5 code 
    styles.css  
  -component3  
    component3.js  // es5 code
    styles.css
```

For the es6 transpile I'm using `babel` and it works great:

```
"build:js": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src/components --out-dir ./lib --ignore spec.js"
```

But i struggle with the `LESS` files. I know i can use [`cpx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx) to copy files and keep the structure:

```
"build:less": "cpx \"./src/components/**/*.less\" ./lib"
```

But i want to copy them while processing each of them and compile it from `LESS` to `CSS`.
There is a [`-t`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx#example) argument for a module transformation of each file passed through the pipeline but i can't find a proper module to pass them through.
I tried `lessc` and `lessify` but it doesn't seem like a good fit.

```
"build:less": "cpx \"./src/components/**/*.less\" ./lib -t [less_compiler_here?]"
```

I don't mind using `webpack` or any other pattern to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question here**
I failed to find a fit solution to my situation. After testing a lot of npm packages i found out that each package provides a small part of the solution to my challenge, I decided to write my own solution.
 [lessc-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lessc-glob)
Basically it takes a `glob` and copy the structure from source to target (using cpx) but it passes each file through a `less` transform stream. Of course it changes the file extension to `.css` in the end. 
This is a very tailored solution to my exact challenge but maybe someone will find it useful.
Feel free to make it better if you want to.

Comment: For me it looks like a use-case for tools like `gulp`/`grunt` and similar.

Comment: @seven-phases-max could be, though i don't think one should use gulp or grunt when he already based his entire project (and maybe other projects) on `npm-scripts`. well, at least in my case that is.